# How to effectively use PyJulia or other non-thread-safe libraries in a background thread or process?

Tags: python, julia, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, fire-and-forget

I have a scenario in my Python application where I have some work that needs to be done in the background, but in a fire-and-forget manner. There are two constraints I'm trying to satisfy:

- The background task uses PyJulia, which is [not thread-safe](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#no-threading-support) and will fail if it is invoked from two different threads in the same process, even if these calls don't happen concurrently.
- It turns out PyJulia also has some heavy lifting to do the first time it is invoked in a given process. It takes a few seconds to initialize before the Julia code gets executed. I don't want to pay this cost every time I call it.

What's the simplest way of handling a situation like this? I imagine that I have to create a single long-lived worker thread or process to which I can continually queue tasks, but I don't want to write custom code to handle all of this if I don't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution I've found, which is satisfactory for my needs, is to use Python's `multiprocessing.Pool` to create a pool containing exactly one process, keep that process pool around for the life of my application, and use `apply_async` to execute the task on that process pool in a fire-and-forget manner:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
...

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process_pool = None

    def my_pyjulia_task(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...

    def run(self, arg1, arg2):
        if not self.process_pool:
            self.process_pool = Pool(processes=1)

        self.process_pool.apply_async(self.my_pyjulia_task, (arg1, arg2))
```

This ensures that PyJulia doesn't block the main execution thread and always runs in the same "background" process (and also the same thread). Apparently `apply_async` also queues up work for that process, since I can call it many times and the tasks are executed in order.

It also wouldn't be hard to use `multiprocessing` tools to enable communication from this process back to the main application, if that ever became necessary.

Comment: given GIL lock in Python this actually seems like something the best you can do. Unless you decide to re-engineer to to call Python from Julia which is simply far more convenient and scalable :-)

Comment: thanks for the comment. yes, I don’t like that I have to think about *which* background thread something like this is running on.